# Trim a string - remove space and parentheses in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, trim

Would someone help me with this please?

In vb.net (VS2013):
a string is in the format: `char12345 (6789).jpg`

trim to the string to: `char12345.jpg`

Basically, I need to trim off the middle part: the space and everything in parentheses (including the parentheses).

will VB's trim function work? or I need to use RegEx...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `Would someone help me with this please` would you post what you have tried, please?  See [Ask]

Comment: _"will VB's trim function work?"_ No. _"or I need to use RegEx"_ Not necessarily.  But at which point are you stuck? Have you done any research into string manipulation, either with or without regexs?

Comment: Are the paratheses always at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex, you could remove the parantheses also with pure string methods:

```
Dim path = "char12345 (6789).jpg"
Dim ext = IO.Path.GetExtension(path)
Dim fn = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
Dim index = fn.IndexOf("(")
If index >= 0 Then fn = fn.Remove(index).Trim()
path = String.Format("{0}{1}", fn, ext)
```

Presumes that they are always directly before the extension or that the part behind them can also be removed. Otherwise it's getting a little bit more complicated:

```
Dim index = fn.IndexOf("(")
If index >= 0 Then
    Dim endindex = fn.LastIndexOf(")", index)
    If endindex >= 0 Then
        fn = fn.Remove(index).Trim() & fn.Substring(endindex + 1)
    Else
        fn = fn.Remove(index).Trim()
    End If
End If
```

Comment: All good comments. Do need to review string manipulation. Mr. Schmelter's solution is very useful. InbetweenWeekends' solution works with the specific format I stated, but I realized some strings doesn't have parentheses. A check for Index >= 0 is necessary for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Given your input, you can accomplish this with `Split`

```
Dim str as String = "char12345 (6789).jpg"
Console.Write(str.Split(" ")(0) & "." & str.Split(".")(1))
```